# On LUKS-Dropbear-Arch-Raspberry Pi-System appears error: Can't open '/.cryptdev': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, arch, luks, dropbear

I wrote a script to configure and transform images to an sd card to use them on an Raspberry Pi.

In line 418 of this [script](https://github.com/kevinveenbirkenbach/core-system/blob/master/scripts/image/setup.sh) you will find the following code:

```
    if [ "$encrypt_system" == "y" ]
      then
        # @see https://gist.github.com/gea0/4fc2be0cb7a74d0e7cc4322aed710d38
        rescue_suffix=".$(date +%s).rescue"
        search_hooks="HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck)"
        replace_hooks="HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block sleep netconf dropbear encryptssh filesystems keyboard fsck)"
        mkinitcpio_path="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
        mkinitcpio_rescue_path="$mkinitcpio_path$rescue_suffix"
        search_modules="MODULES=()"
        replace_modules="MODULES=(g_cdc usb_f_acm usb_f_ecm smsc95xx g_ether)"
        root_mapper_path="/dev/mapper/root"
        fstab_path="/mnt/etc/fstab"
        fstab_rescue_path="$fstab_path$rescue_suffix"
        crypttab_path="/mnt/etc/crypttab"
        crypttab_rescue_path="$crypttab_path$rescue_suffix"
        boot_txt_path="/boot/boot.txt"
        boot_txt_rescue_path="$boot_txt_path$rescue_suffix"
        boot_txt_delete_line=$(echo "part uuid \${devtype} \${devnum}:2 uuid" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g')
        boot_txt_setenv_origin=$(echo "setenv bootargs console=ttyS1,115200 console=tty0 root=PARTUUID=\${uuid} rw rootwait smsc95xx.macaddr=\"\${usbethaddr}\"" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g')
        boot_txt_setenv_replace=$(echo "setenv bootargs console=ttyS1,115200 console=tty0 ip=::::$target_hostname:eth0:dhcp cryptdevice=$encrypted_partition_path:root root=$root_mapper_path rw rootwait smsc95xx.macaddr=\"\${usbethaddr}\""| sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')
        info "Setup encryption..." &&
        question "Type in encryption password: " && read -r luks_password
        question "Repeat encryption password:" && read -r luks_password_repeat
        if [ "$luks_password" != "$luks_password_repeat" ]
          then
            error "Passwords didn't match."
        fi
        (
        echo "pacman --noconfirm -S --needed $(get_packages "server/luks") &&"
        echo "cp -v /home/$target_username/.ssh/authorized_keys /etc/dropbear/root_key &&"
        echo "cp -v $mkinitcpio_path $mkinitcpio_rescue_path &&"
        echo "sed -i 's/$search_modules/$replace_modules/g' $mkinitcpio_path &&"
        echo "sed -i 's/$search_hooks/$replace_hooks/g' $mkinitcpio_path &&"
        echo "echo \"Content of $mkinitcpio_path:\$(cat \"$mkinitcpio_path\")\" &&"
        #Concerning mkinitcpio warning @see https://gist.github.com/imrvelj/c65cd5ca7f5505a65e59204f5a3f7a6d
        echo "mkinitcpio -P &&"
        echo "echo '$luks_password' | sudo cryptsetup -v luksFormat -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h sha512 --use-random -i 1000 $encrypted_partition_path &&"
        echo "echo '$luks_password' | sudo cryptsetup -v luksOpen $encrypted_partition_path root &&"
        echo "mkfs.ext4 $root_mapper_path &&"
        echo "mount $root_mapper_path /mnt &&"
        echo "rsync --info=progress2 -axHAX / /mnt/ &&"
        echo "cp -v $fstab_path $fstab_rescue_path &&"
        echo "echo $root_mapper_path' /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1' >> $fstab_path &&"
        echo "echo \"Content of $fstab_path:\$(cat \"$fstab_path\")\" &&"
        echo "cp -v $crypttab_path $crypttab_rescue_path &&"
        echo "echo 'root '$encrypted_partition_path' none luks' >> $crypttab_path &&"
        echo "echo \"Content of $crypttab_path:\$(cat \"$crypttab_path\")\" &&"
        #boot.txt just works with raspberry pi 3 @todo Needs to be implemented for arch raspbery pi 4
        echo "cp -v $boot_txt_path $boot_txt_rescue_path &&"
        echo "sed -i 's/$boot_txt_delete_line//g' $boot_txt_path &&"
        echo "sed -i 's/$boot_txt_setenv_origin/$boot_txt_setenv_replace/g' $boot_txt_path &&"
        echo "echo \"Content of $boot_txt_path:\$(cat \"$boot_txt_path\")\" &&"
        echo "cd /boot/ && ./mkscr &&"
        echo "umount $root_mapper_path &&"
        echo "sudo cryptsetup -v luksClose root &&"
        echo "exit || echo 'Error in chroot environment!' echo 'Trying to close decrypted root.'; sudo cryptsetup -v luksClose root"
        ) | chroot "$root_mount_path" /bin/bash || error
    fi
```

This generates the following output:

```
    [INFO]: Setup encryption... 
    [QUESTION]: Type in encryption password:  
    test
    [QUESTION]: Repeat encryption password: 
    test
    warning: rsync-3.2.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: autoconf-2.69-7 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: automake-1.16.2-3 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: binutils-2.35-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: bison-3.6.4-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: fakeroot-1.24-2 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: file-5.39-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: findutils-4.7.0-2 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: flex-2.6.4-3 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: gawk-5.1.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: gcc-10.2.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: gettext-0.21-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: grep-3.4-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: groff-1.22.4-3 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: gzip-1.10-3 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: libtool-2.4.6+44+gb9b44533-14 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: m4-1.4.18-3 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: make-4.3-3 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: pacman-5.2.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: patch-2.7.6-8 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: pkgconf-1.7.3-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: sed-4.8-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: sudo-1.9.3.p1-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: texinfo-6.7-3 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: which-2.21-5 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: uboot-tools-2020.04-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: dropbear-2020.80-1 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: mkinitcpio-utils-0.0.3-5 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: mkinitcpio-netconf-0.0.5-2 is up to date -- skipping
    warning: mkinitcpio-dropbear-0.0.3-6 is up to date -- skipping
     there is nothing to do
    '/home/alarm/.ssh/authorized_keys' -> '/etc/dropbear/root_key'
    '/etc/mkinitcpio.conf' -> '/etc/mkinitcpio.conf.1601472644.rescue'
    Content of /etc/mkinitcpio.conf:# vim:set ft=sh
    # MODULES
    # The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
    # run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
    # in this array.  For instance:
    #     MODULES=(piix ide_disk reiserfs)
    MODULES=(g_cdc usb_f_acm usb_f_ecm smsc95xx g_ether)
    
    # BINARIES
    # This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
    # wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
    # override the actual binaries included by a given hook
    # BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
    BINARIES=()
    
    # FILES
    # This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
    # as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
    FILES=()
    
    # HOOKS
    # This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
    # modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
    # Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
    # order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H ' for
    # help on a given hook.
    # 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
    # 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
    # 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
    # Examples:
    ##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
    ##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
    #    HOOKS=(base)
    #
    ##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
    ##   work as a sane default
    #    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
    #
    ##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
    ##   No autodetection is done.
    #    HOOKS=(base udev block filesystems)
    #
    ##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
    ##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
    #    HOOKS=(base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems)
    #
    ##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
    #    HOOKS=(base udev block lvm2 filesystems)
    #
    ##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
    #    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block sleep netconf dropbear encryptssh filesystems keyboard fsck)
    
    # COMPRESSION
    # Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, gzip compression
    # is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
    #COMPRESSION="gzip"
    #COMPRESSION="bzip2"
    #COMPRESSION="lzma"
    #COMPRESSION="xz"
    #COMPRESSION="lzop"
    #COMPRESSION="lz4"
    
    # COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
    # Additional options for the compressor
    #COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=()
    ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux-aarch64.preset: 'default'
      -> -k 5.8.9-2-ARCH -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    ==> Starting build: 5.8.9-2-ARCH
      -> Running build hook: [base]
      -> Running build hook: [udev]
      -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
      -> Running build hook: [modconf]
      -> Running build hook: [block]
      -> Running build hook: [sleep]
      -> Running build hook: [netconf]
      -> Running build hook: [dropbear]
    Generating dss host key for dropbear ...
    Unknown key type 'dss'
    Usage: /usr/sbin/dropbearkey -t  -f  [-s bits]
    -t type Type of key to generate. One of:
            rsa
            ecdsa
            ed25519
    -f filename    Use filename for the secret key.
                   ~/.ssh/id_dropbear is recommended for client keys.
    -s bits Key size in bits, should be a multiple of 8 (optional)
               ECDSA has sizes 256 384 521 
               Ed25519 has a fixed size of 256 bits
    -y      Just print the publickey and fingerprint for the
            private key in .
    dropbear_rsa_host_key : sha1!! a1:7b:17:e0:43:2e:2c:d2:8e:d3:17:21:15:fb:45:4a:7f:7e:96:57
    dropbear_ecdsa_host_key : sha1!! 14:7e:96:5c:1d:8e:60:bd:fb:70:21:93:d5:c7:1e:71:85:49:02:ef
      -> Running build hook: [encryptssh]
      -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
      -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
      -> Running build hook: [fsck]
    ==> Generating module dependencies
    ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    bsdtar: Failed to set default locale
    bsdtar: Failed to set default locale
    ==> Image generation successful
    ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux-aarch64.preset: 'fallback'
      -> -k 5.8.9-2-ARCH -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img -S autodetect
    ==> Starting build: 5.8.9-2-ARCH
      -> Running build hook: [base]
      -> Running build hook: [udev]
      -> Running build hook: [modconf]
      -> Running build hook: [block]
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
      -> Running build hook: [sleep]
      -> Running build hook: [netconf]
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: rsi_sdio
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: rsi_usb
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: atmel
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: at76c50x_usb
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: rtl8723ae
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: zd1201
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: zd1211rw
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: prism54
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: p54pci
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: p54usb
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: orinoco_usb
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wcn36xx
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: b43legacy
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: b43
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: ipw2100
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: ipw2200
    ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: mt7603e
      -> Running build hook: [dropbear]
    Generating dss host key for dropbear ...
    Unknown key type 'dss'
    Usage: /usr/sbin/dropbearkey -t  -f  [-s bits]
    -t type Type of key to generate. One of:
            rsa
            ecdsa
            ed25519
    -f filename    Use filename for the secret key.
                   ~/.ssh/id_dropbear is recommended for client keys.
    -s bits Key size in bits, should be a multiple of 8 (optional)
               ECDSA has sizes 256 384 521 
               Ed25519 has a fixed size of 256 bits
    -y      Just print the publickey and fingerprint for the
            private key in .
    dropbear_rsa_host_key : sha1!! a1:7b:17:e0:43:2e:2c:d2:8e:d3:17:21:15:fb:45:4a:7f:7e:96:57
    dropbear_ecdsa_host_key : sha1!! 14:7e:96:5c:1d:8e:60:bd:fb:70:21:93:d5:c7:1e:71:85:49:02:ef
      -> Running build hook: [encryptssh]
      -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
      -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
      -> Running build hook: [fsck]
    ==> Generating module dependencies
    ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    bsdtar: Failed to set default locale
    bsdtar: Failed to set default locale
    ==> Image generation successful
    Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 54
    Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 54
    WARNING: Device /dev/mmcblk1p3 already contains a 'crypto_LUKS' superblock signature.
    Existing 'crypto_LUKS' superblock signature (offset: 0 bytes) on device /dev/mmcblk1p3 will be wiped.
    Existing 'crypto_LUKS' superblock signature (offset: 16384 bytes) on device /dev/mmcblk1p3 will be wiped.
    Key slot 0 created.
    Command successful.
    Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 54
    Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 54
    Key slot 0 unlocked.
    Command successful.
    mke2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
    Creating filesystem with 14724352 4k blocks and 3686400 inodes
    Filesystem UUID: da0071a7-ef0d-4051-9461-145add2be871
    Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424
    
    Allocating group tables: done                            
    Writing inode tables: done                            
    Creating journal (65536 blocks): done
    Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done   
    
      1,924,493,579  99%    5.42MB/s    0:05:38 (xfr#32483, to-chk=0/43361)    
    '/mnt/etc/fstab' -> '/mnt/etc/fstab.1601472644.rescue'
    Content of /mnt/etc/fstab:# Static information about the filesystems.
    # See fstab(5) for details.
    
    #      
    /dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot   vfat    defaults        0       0
    /dev/mapper/root /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
    '/mnt/etc/crypttab' -> '/mnt/etc/crypttab.1601472644.rescue'
    Content of /mnt/etc/crypttab:# Configuration for encrypted block devices.
    # See crypttab(5) for details.
    
    # NOTE: Do not list your root (/) partition here, it must be set up
    #       beforehand by the initramfs (/etc/mkinitcpio.conf).
    
    #                                                           
    # home         UUID=b8ad5c18-f445-495d-9095-c9ec4f9d2f37    /etc/mypassword1
    # data1        /dev/sda3                                    /etc/mypassword2
    # data2        /dev/sda5                                    /etc/cryptfs.key
    # swap         /dev/sdx4                                    /dev/urandom            swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
    # vol          /dev/sdb7                                    none
    root /dev/mmcblk1p3 none luks
    '/boot/boot.txt' -> '/boot/boot.txt.1601472644.rescue'
    Content of /boot/boot.txt:# After modifying, run ./mkscr
    
    # Set root partition to the second partition of boot device
    
    
    setenv bootargs console=ttyS1,115200 console=tty0 ip=::::home-server:eth0:dhcp cryptdevice=/dev/mmcblk1p3:root root=/dev/mapper/root rw rootwait smsc95xx.macaddr="${usbethaddr}"
    
    if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${kernel_addr_r} /Image; then
      if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${fdt_addr_r} /dtbs/${fdtfile}; then
        if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${ramdisk_addr_r} /initramfs-linux.img; then
          booti ${kernel_addr_r} ${ramdisk_addr_r}:${filesize} ${fdt_addr_r};
        else
          booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r};
        fi;
      fi;
    fi
    Image Name:   U-Boot boot script
    Created:      Wed Sep 30 13:43:18 2020
    Image Type:   ARM Linux Script (uncompressed)
    Data Size:    668 Bytes = 0.65 KiB = 0.00 MiB
    Load Address: 00000000
    Entry Point:  00000000
    Contents:
       Image 0: 660 Bytes = 0.64 KiB = 0.00 MiB
    Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 54
    Unknown host QEMU_IFLA type: 54
    Command successful.
```

When I start the raspberry pi and try to connect to it I get the following output on the terminal:

```
    ssh root@192.168.178.61
    cat: can't open '/.cryptdev': No such file or directory
    Command requires device and mapped name as arguments.
    Connection to 192.168.178.61 closed.
```

I would be glad if somebody could tell me where the bug is and how I solve this problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is solved.
The mistake was using a different device name on the compiling and the productive system.
See https://bbs.archlinux.de/viewtopic.php?pid=377823